# How to say "a bit more" in "Verb + Something + a bit more"

Tags: translation

I'm often stuck with how to use "a bit more" in Chinese in situations like :

```
Verb + something + a bit more
```

> I want to watch TV a bit more
>
> I want to eat spicy noodles a bit more
>
> I want to have a longer walk on the beach
>
> I plan on listening to more music
>
> Can you speak a bit slower ? (I know this one 漫说一点)

I know you can say, for instance :
多吃. (I'm not sure but I think I could also say 多吃一点)
But how would you say "Eat more of something" 多吃那个一点 ？

Nobody taught me this and the problem I have is not with 多/少 before the verb, it is about the grammatical order of the sentence and the words to use if there is something / a direct object complement after the verb.

What's the order ?
Should I only use 我把这个多吃 ？
Are they any other alternatives ?

I take the opportunity to ask as well how to say:

```
Doing + something + too much
```

Verb + something + 太多 /or/ Verb + 太多 + something ？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to watch TV = 我想看電視
>
> I want to watch TV (**a bit more**) = 我想 (**多**) 看 (**一點**) 電視

~

> I want to eat spicy noodles = 我想吃辣面
>
> I want to eat spicy noodles (**a bit more**) = 我想(**多**)吃(**一點**)辣面

~

I want to have a walk on the beach = 我想在沙滩上散步

I want to have a (**longer**) walk on the beach = 我想在沙滩上散(**長一點的**)步

~

> I plan on listening to music = 我打算听音乐
>
> I plan on listening to (**more**) music = 我打算听(**更多的**)音乐
>
> I plan on listening to (**a bit more**) music = 我打算(**多**)听(**一點**)音乐

~

> Can you speak slower ?  = 你能说慢一点吗？
>
> Can you speak (**a bit**) slower ? = 你能(**稍微**)说慢一点吗？

Answer (score 1):

I want to watch a bit more TV.
我还想再看一会儿电视。

I want to eat some more spicy noodles.
我还想要再吃一点麻辣面条。

I want to have a longer walk on the beach.
我还想要在沙滩再散一会儿步。

I plan on listening to more music.
我打算再听一会儿音乐。

Can you speak a bit slower ? (I know this one 漫说一点)
你可以说慢一点吗？